# Logisitc Regression using SciKit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

Can someone please help me to debug this code? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn import linear_model
data = pd.read_csv('Mower.csv')
data = data.values
y = data[:,2]
x = data[:,:2]
y_train = y[:int(0.3*len(y))]
x_train = x[:int(0.3*len(y)),:]
y_validate = y[int(0.3*len((y))):]
x_validate = x[int(0.3*len((y))):,:]
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_hat = clf.predict(x_validate)
```

Gives me following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-a0a54feba3ef> in <module>()
      1 clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression
----> 2 clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
      3 y_hat = clf.predict(x_validate)

TypeError: unbound method fit() must be called with LogisticRegression instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression
```

you want

```
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
```

In the first case, `clf` is set equal to the *class* `linear_model.LogisticRegression`, but in the second case it is set equal to an *instance of* the class `linear_model.LogisticRegression`.

When you call `clf.fit(...)` it is expecting an instance of the class `linear_model.LogisticRegression` as the first argument.  If `clf` is a class, then it is not passed automatically into the first argument, so the `fit` method finds `x_train` instead, an instance of the class `ndarray`.  It then complains, because it was expecting an instance of the class `linear_model.LogisticRegression` instead.

That's what this

```
unbound method fit() must be called with LogisticRegression instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)
```

is trying to say.